# Restoring last page when user logs in, Sessions/Database

Tags: php, database, session

I'm finalising my project, and I want to find how I can restore the users last page when he logs in. Do I need to have a function that save the game, or is there a way I can redirect the user to the room/page he was when he logs in. As I recall, sessions get destroyed as a user logs out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store every user movement inside your website into a database with a filed like `lastPageVisited` and add an updater to every page of your website that update that field with the current page.
Then you could recover that field with a simple query.
But the question is: is it really worth something?